Blender Mesh appears to be clipping from the inside out?
I made this model of a character in Blender and I used a couple of modifiers like mirror, subdivision surface and solidify. I modelled the shirt, pants and coat in separate models. After that I made some materials and rigged the model, but, it's doing this

Truth be told, it's not that bad in material mode:

But, still, it makes things hard to weight paint:

I tried searching, but I didn't find anything similar to this, it's also good to note that I joined the shirt and pants to the base model(which I used skin modifier to make), and deleted the unnecessary faces, but those are with the same problem.
Here are images of the same thing but with Face orientation turned on, a guy told me to do this.

Now here is a image of just the coat, I think it'll help, maybe:



Turn on Face Orientation on the Viewport Overlays dropdown (Top-right of the top toolbar with the overlapping circles) and add an image of your model. - The whole model should be Blue. See my answer here for details.

You mean, add another image of how the model looks now?

Yes. Edit your question and add an image (in Object mode).

Alright, i've done it

Oh, sorry, i used pose mode, but i switched right now on my computer, and i don't really see a difference. but tell me if it needs to be in object mode.

That's ok. It certainly looks as if the normals are inverted on part of the coat but I'm a bit unclear as to why the two sides of the model don't match. Is it already posed? I think you'd better share your Blend file so that someone here can have a look at it. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the full link into it. It's 00:30am here so I'm off to bed!

Done, i linked the blend file in the post. also, to clarify, that "clipping" is happening on the whole model, not just the coat. And i did pose the model to get that "clipping". One more thing is that i translated all the objects and collections on the blend file to english, since they were in brazillian portuguese(my native language), there are also a few backup collections that i made in case of me screwing up somewhere, i think they might come in handy.

I think someone more familiar with rigging clothing than I am will have to answer that one. The only obvious thing I can see at a quick look is that the origin of the coat (orange dot) isn't in the centre of the object in front view but I don't know whether that's causing the problem in this case.

I think that the way default weight paint of the armature was applied to the jacket caused this issue. I would change your work flow a little bit. Keep the clothing items separate from the body until all the weight paint is working correctly, and merge them as the last step. As for easily getting the correct weights on the jacket, It's probably best to not apply the skin modifier or, apply it only once you've got the right weight paint on the jacket mesh pre skin modifier. You can transfer the weights from the body to the jacket using this method https://youtu.be/bR_Vke__voU?si=ubvb9fwCOEdgBq2n. GOod luck, I hope this solves your problem.

So, it's better to make the armature, weight paint, and then apply the skin modifier of the body?

Yeah, It would be much easier to paint the mesh befor applying the skin modifier, which you used on the jacket right? I would transfer the weight from the body first, it saves some work.

I didn't use the skin modifier on the jacket, only on the base character

I see, are there any other modifiers on the jacket? I think the thickness might make it harderfor the weight trasfer to work, but you just have to try it I guess.

I used subdivision surface, mirror and Solidify, but i'll try it.

It worked! Thank you very much
